# List<T> Constructor (IEnumerable<T>) doesn't accept an array created from Array.CreateInstance(Type, Int32)

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I'm a newbie to programming and .net, and I am having a hard time understanding why using the `List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` constructor accepts an array created using `[]`, but does not accept an array created using `Array.CreateInstance(Type, Int32)`.

Here is what works:

```
DirectoryInfo[] dirsArray = foo.GetDirectories();
List<DirectoryInfo> dirsList = new List<DirectoryInfo>(dirsArray);
```

Here is what doesn't:

```
 Array dirsArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(DirectoryInfo), 10); //assume we know 10 is the required length
 List<DirectoryInfo> dirsList = new List<DirectoryInfo>(dirsArray);
```

The above gives the following compiler errors:

```
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.IO.DirectoryInfo>.List(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.IO.DirectoryInfo>)' has some invalid arguments

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Array' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.IO.DirectoryInfo>'
```

But I know that `List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` can accept any `IEnumerable` as an argument. And I know that `System.Array` is `IEnumerable`. Not only because that is in the reference, but because the first example using the `[]` constructor syntax works fine.

So then what is the problem here? Does `Array.CreateInstance` somehow manages to create an array that is not `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Because `Array.CreateInstance` returns an untyped `Array` which does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by using `Array.CreateInstance` anyway? I've personally never found a use for it.

Comment: Actually I wanted to convert ControlCollection to List<Control>, and couldn't figure out how to do it. So I added a step of converting it to an Array first before converting it to a List.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array` class itself is not an `IEnumerable<T>`.You will need to cast result of `Array.CreateInstance`

```
var dirsArray = (DirectoryInfo[]) Array.CreateInstance(typeof(DirectoryInfo), 10);
```

`Array` is the base class for all array types and the implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` is provided at runtime.So it is not possible to use an Array as `IEnumerable<T>` at compile time.From [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, the Array class implements the `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`, `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`, and `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces. **The implementations are provided to arrays at run time**, and as a result, the generic interfaces do not appear in the declaration syntax for the Array class.

Answer (score 2):

because `Array.CreateInstance(Type, Int32)` does not return an `IEnumerable<T>` instance, it returns an `Array` object. If you create an array using [] it will be an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Please take a look at this thread, it's quite explanatory: [Why isn't Array a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324987/why-isnt-array-a-generic-type)

Comment: That's the part that I don't understand. In the reference for CreateInstance it simply states that it returns a System.Array. No mention of it not being in any way different. In the reference for System.Array, it clearly states that it is IEnumerable.

Comment: It is an IEnumerable, just not an IEnumerable<T>

Comment: @GarryWong [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) are two different things.

Comment: OH! Ok, that's what I was missing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`Array.CreateInstance` returns an untyped [Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Array(v=vs.110).aspx) which as you'll notice, doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` (it's not generic), so can't be used with the `List<T>` constructor.

However, what's actually returned for `Array.CreateInstance` is typed, you just have to cast it to the type you want (all typed arrays are derived from the base `Array` class). So you can do this:

```
List<DirectoryInfo> dirsList = new List<DirectoryInfo>((DirectoryInfo[])dirsArray);
```

And it should compile.

That said, I've never found a reason to use `Array.CreateInstance`.

**Update**: Since in the comments to the original question you talk about converting a `ControlCollection` to a `List<Control>`, it should be noted that you can't cast a `ControlCollection` to a typed array. So something like this doesn't work:

```
var lst = (Control[])myControlCollection;
```

Because `ControlCollection` (and a lot of the older, pre-generics, collections in the framework) doesn't derive from `Array`. In that case, since `ControlCollection` implements `IEnumerable`, you can use the [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
var lst = new List<Control>(myControlCollection.Cast<Control>());
```

You can use this trick with a lot of the collection classes in the framework if they implement `IEnumerable`. [MatchCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) to give another example.