# How to remove last two lines from list

Tags: c#, list, indexing

I'm trying to remove last two lines from list, with text document I did it this way:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(doc.txt); 
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(doc.txt, lines.Take(lines.Length - 2).ToArray());
```

but when I'm trying to do the same with list

```
 List<string> myList = new List<string>();
```

this way, I have not result:

```
myList.RemoveAt(myList.Count - 2);
```

Comment: To remove the last two items in a list just call `list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);` twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RemoveAt Method gets an index as parameter. So if you execute this code:

```
list.RemoveAt(myList.Count - 2);
```

You will remove the item on position `myList.Count - 2` instead of 2 items. So if you want to delete the last two items you can do the following:

```
list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
```

Or the better approach is to use `RemoveRange` as abdul suggest in his answer.

Comment: sorry had a typo, did you mean to have list.Count - 2 in your recommendation? wouldn't that result in removing the last line and essentially the 3rd line from the original list?

Comment: @Hack thank you hack I missed that in the hurry :-D. You are right. I correct that.

Comment: @Sebi Hello, yes it is useful for my case

Answer (score 7):

You can use `RemoveRange`, also note index is zero-based, and `Count` is not.

```
list.RemoveRange(list.Count - 2, list.Count - 1);
```

This will remove last two lines inside the `List<string>`

Answer (score -2):

A `List<T>` is not meant to be indexed by element. You need either an array or a `Dictionary` to do that.

So, when you have `list` with all the lines, you will need to find lines by content... or better yet in your example, keep those last 2 lines from being added to the list in the first place, during the IO reading logic.

Comment: The reason why I recommend steering away from using `List` for this is because it is not a collection that is meant to be used by index (ie "last two", "last", "first", etc)

Comment: A list is absolutely meant to be accessed by index.  Under the covers it's just an array that is resized when needed.

Comment: @juharr not by the user it's not. `List<T>` is a dynamic collection, not guaranteed to be sorted or indexed in any particular way at a particular time. If you want to do logic involving accessing elements by index (ie "last two"), then an array is what you want to work with. Or something with a key, such as a `Dictionary`.

Comment: You can determine what the last two items in a list are just as easily as an array, and you can remove them, unlike the array where you can only set them to something else.  A dictionary is a completely different beast where you want access via a key and order is not guaranteed.

Comment: @AaronThomas I don't think you are right here. The Framework won't give you access to list[index] or list.RemoveAt or list.IndexOf etc. if you shouldn't access a list via index. It's common to access a list via index if needed.

Comment: A `List<T>` is a wrapper around an array of `T`, period. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646

Comment: I stand corrected - esp reading this helped me understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324987/why-isnt-array-a-generic-type/15561100#15561100