# Why does a System.Array object have an Add() method?

Tags: arrays, powershell, interface

I fully understand that a System.Array is immutable.

Given that, why does it have an Add() method?

It does not appear in the output of Get-Member.

```
$a = @('now', 'then')
$a.Add('whatever')
```

Yes, I know this fails and I know why it fails. I am not asking for suggestions to use `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` or `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]`.

Comment: To sort of add on to your question, if anyone knows, how do you find the interfaces a type implements using powershell?  I find myself in the msdn a lot trying to figure things out.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 You can call the [`GetInterfaces()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.type.getinterfaces) on a [`Type` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.type) like so: `$a.GetType().GetInterfaces()`

Comment: I just found this out today. It's horrific. I wished they'd fix this: the only safety is a runtime exception, while you would definitely want static analysis here. This is some legacy crap of the worst kind...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`[System.Array]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array) implements [`[System.Collections.IList]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist), and the latter has an [`.Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.system-collections-ilist-add#System_Array_System_Collections_IList_Add_System_Object_) method.

**That `Array` implements `IList`, which is an interface that also covers  *resizable* collections, may be surprising** - it sounds like there are [historical reasons for it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15561100/45375)<sup>[1]</sup>
.

In C#, this surprise is hard to *stumble upon*, because you need to explicitly cast to `IList` or use an `IList`-typed variable in order to even access the `.Add()` method.

By contrast, since version 3, **PowerShell surfaces even a type's *explicit* interface implementations as *direct members* of a given type's instance.** (Explicit interface implementations are those referencing the interface explicitly in their implementation, such as [`IList.Add()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,710) rather than just `.Add()`; explicit interface implementations are not a direct part of the implementing type's public interface, which is why C# requires a cast / interface-typed variable to access them).

As a byproduct of this design, **in *PowerShell* the `.Add()` method can be called *directly* on `System.Array` instances, which makes it easier to stumble upon the problem, because you may not realize that you're invoking an *interface* method**. In the case of an array, the `IList.Add()` implementation (rightfully) throws an exception stating that `Collection was of a fixed size`; the latter is an exception of type [`NotSupportedException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notsupportedexception), which is how types implementing an interface are expected to report non-support for *parts* of an interface.

What helps is that the [`Get-Member` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) and even just referencing a method *without invoking it* - simply by omitting `()` - allow you to inspect a method to determine whether it is native to the type or an interface implementation:

```
PS> (1, 2).Add  # Inspect the definition of a sample array's .Add() method

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
int IList.Add(System.Object value)
```

As you can see, the output reveals that the `.Add()` method belongs to the `Ilist` interface.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> **Optional reading: Collection-related interfaces in .NET with respect to mutability**

<sup>Disclaimer: This is not my area of expertise. If my explanation is incorrect / can stand improvement, do tell us.</sup>

The root of the hierarchy of collection-related interfaces is [`ICollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection) (non-generic, since v1) and [`ICollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1) (generic, since v2).

(They in turn implement [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable) / [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1), whose only member is the `.GetEnumerator()` method.)

While the non-generic `ICollection` interface commendably makes no assumptions about a collection's mutability, its generic counterpart (`ICollection<T>`) unfortunately does - it includes methods for *modifying* the collection (the docs even state the interface's purpose as "to *manipulate* generic collections" (emphasis added)). In the non-generic v1 world, the same had happened, just one level *below*: the non-generic [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist) includes collection-modifying methods.

**By including mutation methods in these interfaces, even *read-only/fixed-size*** lists/collections (those whose number and sequence of elements cannot be changed, but their element values may) **and fully *immutable* lists/collections** (those that additionally don't allow changing their elements' *values*) **were forced to implement the mutating methods**, while indicating non-support for them with [`NotSupportedException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notsupportedexception) exceptions.

While read-only collection *implementations* have existed since v1.1 (e.g, [`ReadOnlyCollectionBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.readonlycollectionbase)), in terms of *interfaces* it wasn't until .NET v4.5 that [`IReadOnlyCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlycollection-1) and [`IImmutableList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.iimmutablelist-1) were introduced (with the latter, along with all types in the [`System.Collections.Immutable` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable), only available as a downloadable NuGet package).

However, since interfaces that derive from (implement) other interfaces can never *exclude* members, neither `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` nor `IImmutableCollection<T>` can derive from `ICollection<T>` and must therefore derive directly from the shared root of enumerables, `IEnumerable<T>`.
Similarly, more specialized interfaces such as [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1) that implement `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` can therefore not implement `IList<T>` and `ICollection<T>`.

More fundamentally, **starting with a clean slate would offer the following solution, which *reverses* the current logic**:

- Make the major collection interfaces *mutation-agnostic*, which means:

  - They should neither offer mutation methods,
  - nor should they make any *guarantees* with respect to immutability.
- Create *sub-interfaces* that:

  - add members depending on the specific level of mutability.
  - make immutability *guarantees*, if needed.

Using the example of `ICollection` and `IList`, we'd get the following interface hierarchy:

```
IEnumerable<T> # has only a .GetEnumerator() method
  ICollection<T>  # adds a .Count property (only)
   IResizableCollection<T> # adds .Add/Clear/Remove() methods
   IList<T> # adds read-only indexed access
    IListMutableElements<T> # adds writeable indexed access
    IResizableList<T> # must also implement IResizableCollection<T>
      IResizableListMutableElements<T> # adds writeable indexed access
    IImmutableList<T> # guarantees immutability
```

<sup>Note: Only the salient methods/properties are mentioned in the comments above.</sup>

Note that these new `ICollection<T>` and `IList<T>` interfaces would offer *no* mutation methods (no `.Add()` methods, ..., no assignable indexing).

`IImmutableList<T>` would differ from `IList<T>` by *guaranteeing* full immutability (and, as currently, offer mutation-of-a-copy-only methods).

`System.Array` could then safely and fully implement `IList<T>`, without consumers of the interface having to worry about `NotSupportedExceptions`.

Answer (score 6):

To "Add" to @mklement0's answer: [[System.Array]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array) implements [[System.Collections.IList]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist) which specifies an [`Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.add?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_IList_Add_System_Object_) method.

But to answer why have an [`Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.add?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_IList_Add_System_Object_) if it doesn't work? Well, we haven't looked at the other properties, i.e. [`IsFixedSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.isfixedsize?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_IList_IsFixedSize) :

```
PS > $a = @('now', 'then')
PS > $a.IsFixedSize
True
```

So, a `[System.Array]` is just a `[System.Collections.IList]` that is a Fixed Size. When we look back at the [`Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.add?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_IList_Add_System_Object_) method, it explicitly defines that if the List is Read-Only or Fixed Size, throw [`NotSupportedException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notsupportedexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) which it does.

I believe the essence is not, *"Let's have a function that just throws an error message for no reason"*, or to expand on it, *No other reason than to fulfill an Interface*, but it actually is providing a warning that **you are legitimately doing something that you shouldn't do**.

It's the typical Interface ideas, you can have an `IAnimal` type, with an `GetLeg()` method. This method would be used 90% of all animals, which makes it a good reason for implementing into the base Interface, but would throw an error when you use it against a  `Snake` object because you didn't first check the `.HasFeet` property first.

The `Add()` method is a really good method for a List Interface, because it is an essential method for Non-Readonly and Non-Fixed length lists. We are the ones being stupid by not checking that the list is not `IsFixedSize` before calling an `Add()` method that would not work. i.e. this falls into the category of `$null` checks before trying to use things.

Comment: Fair points, but you could argue that there should be an intermediate `IFixedSizeList` interface, which would avoid these problems. What obscures matters is that PowerShell implicitly exposes even the explicitly implemented `IList` members as if they were direct members of arrays, so to a casual PowerShell user it appears that `.Add()` is just another method available on an array - the interface provenance is obscured.

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation. I just think the tool(s) could do more for the developer to avoid writing such code.

Comment: @lit: That PowerShell surfaces interface implementation as direct members _generally_ makes sense in a dynamic, type-flexible language such as PowerShell; in some cases - such as this prominent one - the unfortunate side effect is that you may walk into errors without fully understanding why. PowerShell can't really prevent these errors categorically, because it would have to anticipate all type-interface combinations, which is obviously impractical (and cherry-picking a few high-profile nonsensical combinations is not a good idea).