# Why don't array types have Add() method although they implement IList<T>?

Tags: arrays, .net, interface, icollection

Array types such as int[] implement many interfaces, and IList is one of them. IList requires to implement the Add(T) method (because IList inherits from ICollection).

I am writing a "CircularArray" class which contains an array in itself, but doesn't have any index out of range exceptions because of being circular. 
The class's definition is this:

```
public class CircularArray<T> : ICloneable, IList<T>, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable
```

It should implement all interfaces Arrays do, so i have to implement The Add method. But... Arrays don't have this method, although they implement the "ICollection" interface.

How is it all done for arrays so that they can implement the ICollection interface and not have Add method? I want to do the same for my CircularArray class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324987/why-isnt-array-a-generic-type, read Daniel's answer

Comment: thanks for the link, now I understand why is that. But I still got one more question - how do I hide the Add method like arrays do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation is in Daniel's answer in the other topic. To do what you want to achieve is to use explicit interface implementation.

```
    interface ILeft
    {
        int P { get;}
    }   
    class Middle : ILeft
    {
        int ILeft.P { get { return 0; } }
    }

var mid= new Middle();
var abc = mid.P // invalid;
var abc2 = (mid as ILeft).P; //valid
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I could make implementation methods private, I saw that yesterday and got shoked because I always thought they had to be public... now I understand :D